# Oracle NUMBER Comparisons

Tags: oracle, types

Generally in programming, the floating point data types should not be compared for equality since the values stored are very often an approximation.

Can two non-integer Oracle NUMBER values be compared reliably for equality since they are stored differently (base-10)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Oracle NUMBER types are precise. They're more like integers with a scale than float/double types. So a NUMBER(10,3) has 10 digits, 3 after the decimal point, which is really a 10 digit integer with a scale of 3. In fact, that's precise how Java BigDecimals work (being a BigInteger plus a scale internally).

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209

Comment: If two NUMBER types contain a number such as 10.32 and you compare them, they will be equal and it won't matter how you get 10.32. This is different to floating point numbers. 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.5 in NUMBER types but not in floating point math necessary. That's what I mean by precise (assuming the NUMBER type has a scale of at least 1).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle `NUMBER` types are stored as sets of centesimal digits (that is `base 100`, not `base 10`), one digit per byte.

The first byte represents the exponent, other bytes represent mantissa.

That means that for extremely large numbers, even the integer numbers can be rounded:

```
SELECT  10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -
        10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
FROM    dual


---
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle guarantees 38 digits of precision in a NUMBER, although 40 can be represented.  See [Oracle Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3819) for a reference.