# Oracle's lack of a Bit datatype for table columns

Tags: oracle, boolean

Oracle does not support a `bit` datatype or any other type for true/false scenarios. Does one use the `char(1)` field instead by using a specific letter to denote yes / true regardless of culture specific issues?

Instead of `char` should it be `Number(1,0)` for this instead - 0 being considered false / no, anything else being interpreted as true / yes?

Is this viable?

---

Why does Oracle not support a simple boolean type?

Comment: Under all reserve, doesn't Oracle offer a BOOL or BOOLEAN (perhaps is it only with the latest versions...) data type? I can't really remember clearly. I haven't done Oracle for more than two years now. Anyway, NUMBER(1) is just fine, it says what it needs to, just like a BIT - 0 or 1, a NUMBER(1) - 0 or 1, what's the difference?

Comment: @Will: Number(1, 0) can be any single digit number (0-9), not just 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes, of course! But have you no control over your datatable column values?

Comment: @Will: Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't provide either Bit or Boolean as acceptable data types for data in tables... As for your restricting to 0 or 1, I agree with you - this is the way we would be going if I were the Technical Lead on our project - but alas, I'm not...

Comment: See also similar question on boolean data type:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boolean Field in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle)

Comment: #squirmingwhilelearningoracle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer char(1) over number(1), since with some reasonable choice of characters, it is obvious which character has which boolean meaning.

Of course you should fight all the different varations, choose one and ensure it's use by putting check constraints on the columns.

Although it probably is to late in your case, generating the schema from another tool often takes care at least of the consistency issue. I personally prefer hibernate for this purpose, but that is very situation specific.

And of course that is a glaring obmission. To make it worse, PL/SQL has a boolean, but you can't use it in SQL statements.

Comment: Both this and Thilo's answers are good - but I've accepted this one because of the advice to enforce compliance through check constraints...

Seems like the real answer is "Everyone does their own thing, there is no standard..."

Comment: You can also name the column accordingly such as UPDATE_ALLOWED_YN

Answer (score 34):

Use a `CHAR(1)`, and a constraint to allow only `1` and `0`.

...

```
col CHAR(1),
CONSTRAINT cons_atable_col1 CHECK (col1 IN ('1','0'))
```

Comment: That is what I was going to write after doing some further research on the case. Anyway, here's a link that should help. http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/07/oracle-boolean.html Furthermore, you can define yourself a user type which would be BIT, for instance, then accepting only those constrainted values. Another useful link: http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45441

Comment: Don't forget about  "Default 0  Not Null", if necessary. I tested necessity - to avoid null inserting

Answer (score 21):

I'm not an English native so I tend to use either 1 and 0 or '1' and '0'. Using 'Y' and 'N' make little sense if you aren't coding in English (yes, native language coding does exist). Using 'SI' and 'NO' or 'S' and 'N' doesn't look professional (just like naming variables with accented letters). Ones and zeroes, on the contrary, are pretty standard if you've coded in C, PHP or JavaScript. In any case, I always add the appropriate constraint to disallow any other character. Apart from subjective issues, I don't think there're noticeable performance gain in choosing CHAR or NUMBER. I like numbers a little more because I don't need to quote them :)

I agree it's a glaring omission but I've read seriously heated discussions on the subject in some Oracle forums; it's a kind of religious issue. Some claim that booleans belong to application data types and have no place in the database core. Honestly, I believe it's one of those We Have Been So Long Without It That We Had Better Say It Was On Purpose things.

By the way, MySQL has a BOOLEAN type but it's a synonym for TINYINT(1) so it eventually equals to 1 and 0; which is fine, because it also has the constants TRUE and FALSE that evaluate to 1 and 0.

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with you - and yes, I have done some C / PHP in my past. I definitely prefer numerics, but I'm surprised to find they take more space (see above)

Comment: +1 for "We-Have-Been-So-Long-Without-It-That-We-Had-Better-Say-It-Was-On-Purpose"  We ought to coin that phrase: WHBSLWITWHBSIWOP.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595) discussion on the topic. Gives an Oracle-centric view on the issue.

As for storage, char(1) is actually a bit (no pun intended) more efficient:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE xx (c CHAR(1), n NUMBER);

Table created

SQL> insert into xx values('T', 1);

1 row inserted

SQL> select dump(c), dump(n) from xx;

DUMP(C)             DUMP(N)
------------------- -------------
Typ=96 Len=1: 84    Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
```

Comment: That's very interesting - and not what I expected.

I still personally feel that numerics have more clarity... I read the Ask Tom discussion before seeing your post (Googled around), but I don't agree with his justification from not having a boolean / bit...

Comment: @Martin: See this SO discussion for further enlightenment, paying particular attention to Quassnoi's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087210/oracle-number-comparisons/1087873#1087873

Comment: @Martin: I agree, there's no logical reason to exclude the BOOLEAN type in the database, only pragmatic ones. Oracle is a bit schizophrenic on the issue, since they do have a BOOLEAN type in their PL/SQL language. That alone is the source of a great deal of confusion to Oracle programmers the first time they bump into it.

Comment: Thanks for that - didn't know they were stored as centesmimal... My background before this job was largely concerned with MS-SQL, and I have to say in many ways I am beginning to miss it!

Answer (score 5):

According to this Oracle guide - you should use NUMBER(3). Crazy, but true.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm

Comment: "According to this Oracle guide", well actually it is a conversion table from MsSQL to Oracle. So I don't know if you really should use this a guide to use `NUMBER(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

Number(1) is no better than char(1). Especially if it will be in addition to the existing char(1). That will just add to the confusion.

FWIW, Oracle in internal views (such as USER_TAB_COLUMNS) uses varchar2(3) (YES and NO). Not sure if they are 100% consistent here, though.

Comment: My reason for thinking of Number(1,0) was that if nothing else a value would have a definite defined meaning. 

I take your point about whatever we do having to co-exist with the code of the past, but that's unavoidable - and not as undesirable as simply leaving the situation as it currently is...

I was also hoping that the numeric nature would be easier for the server to process, and therefore perhaps (negligably) quicker.

Would you care to offer a candidate datatype?

Comment: number(1) might be a little smaller on disc space, but except for huge tables consisting almost only of 'boolean' this should be neglectable. Also you always have the options of compression and bitmap indices which might solve some of the space related negative effects.

Comment: @Jens: Actually, number(1) is bigger. See my answer.

Comment: Oracle uses, variously, 'Y'/'N', 'YES'/'NO', 'ENABLED'/'DISABLED', and even '    Y'/'    N' (see all_tables.cache column), + a few others. Consistency doesn't even get a look in.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but until the latest release of oracle is used it is still a valid question.

I would solve the problem this way:
Create a table which holds the possible values for true/false plus localized display text f.e.
T$KEYWORDS
ITEMNO ITEMTEXT ITEMTEXT_DE ITEMTEXT_FE ...
0      False    Falsch
1      True     Wahr

Instead of True/False this could be also Selected, Not Selected, etc.

And then add a foreigh key to your column to this table. That way you have only valid values and they do not change with localization.

ANother good solution imho is using a check constraint on your data column. This ofc does not work if your values could be different in the same database/column depending on localization of clients.

`alter table tblLocations add flag number CONSTRAINT <constraintname> CHECK (flag IN (1,0));`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle internally uses "bits" (not a datatype per se) in different Data Dictionary views.

For example, dba_users view has :

```
..
        , DECODE (BITAND (u.spare1, 128), 128, 'YES', 'NO')
..
        , DECODE (BITAND (u.spare1, 256), 256, 'Y', 'N')
..
```

which shows a way to workaround this in a way. If you don't have to modify "boolean" bits often, you could employ the same approach that Oracle had since Oracle 6 (at least). Create a table with a NUMBER column, and a VIEW on top of that that hides complexity of BITAND operations.

ps. On a side note, Oracle JDBC has a "Bit" datatype https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleTypes.html#BIT as well as you already know PL/SQL has Boolean. Although it probably doesn't help you much. See BITAND approach above if it suites your case.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/char.html
[image]

As DCookie said, char(1) is more efficient.
Because VARCHAR2(VARCHAR) empty contains 1 byte, but when we store 1 character then empty 1 byte size + with character 1 byte size --> 2 byte need to store 1 character in varchar