# oracle select like as column

Tags: oracle, select, sql-order-by, sql-like

Hi I need to correct this query, which ends with error:

> missing right parenthesis

what's nonsense, problem is probably somewhere else

```
SELECT name, 
      (name LIKE '%adam%') AS score 
  FROM names 
 ORDER BY score DESC
```

If is not possible use LIKE in SELECT part, how is possible to list "ADAMS" first ?

Comment: (name LIKE '%adam%') in columns and not in where clause?

Comment: Are you sure you have that right? AFAIK `LIKE` is only used in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes, I use MySQL typing style, that's didn't work in Oracle. Question is how correct query to be functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT name, 
       (CASE WHEN (name LIKE '%adam%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score
FROM names 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean datatype, so selecting a boolean value is illegal.

See
[Is there a boolean type in oracle databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a SQL in the order by by replacing the score column