# which is best data type to store booelan values in postgresql in comparision with less memory?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

which data type is best suited to store boolean value in postgresql 9.2 in compare of memory. please i am confusing that should i use bit or TINYINT or boolean to store boolean values. And which one is supported by ms sql server,oracle and postgresql databases. Please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: I usually use a `some_flag number(1) not null check (some_flag in (0,1))` in Oracle. If you want something portable you can do that in other DBMS as well (not in MySQL though - it still does not support check constraint

Comment: Frankly I don't think anything other than "int2" / "smallint" will be portable. Way better off using DB-specific datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql supports the `boolean` type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html

In MS SQL Server `bit` type uses for storing boolean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Oracle doesn't support `boolean` type, but it possible to store boolean values in `CHAR(1)` as `Y/N` or in `NUMBER(1)` as `0/1`: [Is there a boolean type in oracle databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases)

Comment: Hi MikkaRin, thanks for responding fast but oracle doesn't support for boolean type.