# Netbeans: add boolean column on Database

Tags: database, netbeans

I am starting modifying my DB trought Netbeans. I am now creating a new column which must contain a boolean value, and that option is not shown on the Type list for the new coumn. Neither Bool or anything similar to boolean.

Which is the option I must select to create a boolean? I know this could be done with an integer value but as every Status field has been created till now as a Boolean, I'd like to keep it this way.

Netbeans Version 7.4

[image: List]

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: I do not understand the question. if db=database, I am using my own database.. are you asking about some version or similar?

Comment: yes what is your database vendor?

Comment: On database product version: 5.6.12-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Database vendors do not support the boolean datatype in their implementations for the obvious reasons of 3-values logic: null, true, false which is not very convenient for a 2-logic datatype.

I suggest you use the int datatype treating anything but zero as true, or anything positive as true.

You can find other answers to similar questions here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518356/why-doesnt-oracle-support-boolean-datatype
- [Is there a boolean type in oracle databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll tick in 8 minutes.