# Spring StoredProcedure with Boolean Input Parameter

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Calling plsql from java when you need to pass boolean parameter is tricky and as Oracle suggests you can:

> For example, to wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL booleans, you
>   can create a stored procedure that takes a character or number from
>   JDBC and passes it to the original procedure as BOOLEAN, or, for an
>   output parameter, accepts a BOOLEAN argument from the original
>   procedure and passes it as a CHAR or NUMBER to JDBC. Similarly, to
>   wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL records, you can create a
>   stored procedure that handles a record in its individual components
>   (such as CHAR and NUMBER). To wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL
>   tables, you can break the data into components or perhaps use Oracle
>   collection types.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#34_05

Ok it works, but what if I have to use http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html object? Passing just Types.BOOLEAN throws java.sql.SQLException and claims wrong type. Do I still need wrapper function?

Comment: AFAIK Oracle's `BOOLEAN` isn't a type for procedure users. Your parameter should be `NUMBER` and from app it would be very simple to convert `boolean` to `0/1` before procedure call. And don't break your mind on the matter.

Comment: just pass a 0/1 through, there is no boolean in oracle

Comment: @Jaiwo99 there is of course a BOOLEAN type in Oracle DB http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes004.htm

Comment: @ArtemBilan the procedure has input parameter of type http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes004.htm and its developed by another developer, so I cannot simply modify the interface. We have a wrapper function for it but my question is if there is maybe some workaround solution for it when you use StoredProcedure implementation.

Comment: No, you can't populate PL/SQL types to the SQL expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases