# Wrong type expression

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting a runtime error for my function below. I am not sure why as I am passing in integers but it is complaining about strings.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO
( 
  col1 IN NUMBER,
  col2 IN NUMBER
)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   BAR BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  DECLARE FOO NUMBER; 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT 1 INTO FOO FROM DUAL;
  END;
  RETURN BAR;
END FOO;

SELECT FOO(1, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

> ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is
>   of wrong type
>   06552. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 7

Comment: You cannot use BOOLEAN in SQL. But you can use 1 / 0 for true / false

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases

Comment: ok, i switch the boolean to char and am returning 1 or 0; works now.

Comment: The strange thing is that at compile time the compiler does not complain about declaring variables as type Boolean.

Comment: It is not strange, you can declare a variable as BOOLEAN in PLSQL context, but not in SQL. Your function will work without problem in PLSQL context.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle actually doesn't have BOOLEAN type. You need to use flags instead. It is a little confusing what you are trying to do in your code, since you aren't using `col1` or `col2` nor even attempting to set `BAR`.

You can do something like this though, if applicable:

```
DECODE(flag, 1, 'TRUE', 2, 'FALSE')
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO
( 
  col1 IN NUMBER,
  col2 IN NUMBER
)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
vs_return VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1 INTO FOO FROM DUAL;

        vs_return := 'TRUE';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            vs_return := 'FALSE';
    END;

    RETURN vs_return;
END FOO;
```