# Mapping Java boolean to Oracle Number column with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a property created like this in my model:

```
    public class Client {
        private Boolean active;
}
```

My RDBMS is Oracle and the `active` column is of type `NUMBER(1,0)`.

How can I use the Restrictions API to achieve the following functionality?

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active"),object.isActive());
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Hibernate maps the `Boolean` Java type to Oracle `NUMBER(1,0)` automatically.

So, you can use a `Boolean` value in your entity mappings, JPQL or Criteria queries and the generated SQL will use the database `NUMBER(1,0)` format instead.

Comment: just for those who are wondering, number(1) is mapped to true and number(0) to false

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to use Boolean, you should use boolean instead to prevent NPE, cause boolean value just has two available values - true or false. What does it mean null for boolean?? It's a rare case when you need wrapper type Boolean.
Oracle - number(1) default 0 not null.

Comment: A null Boolean can mean unknown or unspecified.  Not to say you always need that distinction.

Comment: in this case you should use Enum, which is suitable for this. Boolean means true or false, nothing more. If you need to have third state - use enum.

Comment: Sorry, but "boolean" means true or false, nothing more. "Boolean" means true, false, or unspecified. Just like the difference between "long" and "Long"

Comment: how unspecified should be treated for boolean type? If there are more than 3 values of some kind of something it's definitely a sign that it should be an enum.

Comment: If the column is nullable, then use Boolean. Boolean can hold the third possibility, "unspecified". If the column is not nullable, then use boolean. Nullable column is not a reason to use Enum.