# Equivalent of oracle type boolean in sap

Tags: oracle, plsql, abap

I have a problem with calling a stored procedure from ABAP.
I use standard ABAP class cl_sql_statement and it's methods execute_procedure and set_param. Called procedure, for example, has a single Boolean input parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_boolean (
  p_in_flag   BOOLEAN
) IS
```

ABAP snippet

```
DATA: ld_e_bool type char5,
      ld_o_stat type ref to cl_sql_statement,
      ld_r_data type ref to data.
***************************
ld_e_bool = 'FALSE'.
get references of ld_e_bool into ld_r_data. 
ld_o_stat->set_param(DATA_REF = ld_r_data).
ld_o_stat->execute_procedure( 'print_boolean' ).
********************************************
```

After the call I catch an exception which says something like: 'wrong number or types of arguments'. Maybe I need another type than char5... Any help would be appreciated.

Some observation:
  The JDBC drivers do not support the passing of BOOLEAN parameters to PL/SQL stored procedures( suggest wrapping the PL/SQL procedure with a second PL/SQL procedure). But i dont want to use the above option becuase there are already lot of packages/SP's are available.

Comment: will the boolean value that youa re passing be the same every time? if so you could give it a default value which may or may not get around the error you are getting.

Comment: check this SCN post out, it may help https://scn.sap.com/thread/517601

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use default value. That about your reference, i  just viewed in direction of native sql statement, but i didn't find any way for to use execute procedure statement for my case. In sap doc say:
"For actual parameters, you can use literals or host variables identified by a colon (:);"
In case of literal There isn't for TRUE or FALSE special equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SAP doc say:

> Almost all SQL statements that are valid for the addressed database system can be included between EXEC and ENDEXEC

Maybe if i try put in this section native pl/sql code i get result...

Edit: I put this code snip and it's ok.

```
EXEC SQL.
   BEGIN
     print_boolean(TRUE); 
   END;
ENDEXEC.
```

But there is one problem. This sql statement have static form only.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG) is unclear on how PL/SQL boolean values are actually represented. There is also a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases) that discusses the use of boolean types in Oracle database fields (not really relevant here, but provides some background).

From the PL/SQL documentation:

> The BOOLEAN datatype takes no parameters. Only the values TRUE, FALSE, and NULL can be assigned to a BOOLEAN variable.
>
> You cannot insert the values TRUE and FALSE into a database column. You cannot select or fetch column values into a BOOLEAN variable. Functions called from a SQL query cannot take any BOOLEAN parameters. Neither can built-in SQL functions such as TO_CHAR; to represent BOOLEAN values in output, you must use IF-THEN or CASE constructs to translate BOOLEAN values into some other type, such as 0 or 1, 'Y' or 'N', 'true' or 'false', and so on.

In light of that, and I know you don't want to, you may need to change the type of parameter you pass into the stored procedure (e.g., use a single character or integer) and then use logic to treat that as a boolean.

Comment: Thx for your answer and I i apologize for some inaccuracy which exist in my post. I can't revise this procedure, because this is not only my unwillingness and point in license agreement.