# how to get a boolan value useing select statement of SQL

Tags: java, sql

Hi people I have a problem.

I have a table in Oracle database called employee and I have a HTML form. I will read some parameters from the form and I want to run a query on the employee table and I just want to know whether that value is present in the table or not.

Comment: That's a not a problem. Or even a question.

Comment: OK, what have you done? Because that's 1 or 2 hours of work, even if you don't know how to do the query.

Comment: There is no boolean value in Oracle SQL according to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases

Comment: What is the backend language you're using? You could just check for 'nullity' with that language on the database result.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM Employees 
WHERE EXISTS (<insert predicate>)
```