# How does Liquibase map boolean for oracle?

Tags: liquibase

Known fact: Oracle does not support Boolean natively.
So it is recommended to use either Char(1) or Number(1) and then creating a constraint to limit the values to Y/N or 0/1.

That being said.
When creating a boolean for an oracle database, Liquibase creates a number(1).
Does anyone know if it also creates the database constraints?
i.e.: "check (bool in (0,1))"

http://dba-presents.com/index.php/liquibase/29-liquibase-3-3-x-data-types-mapping-table

Comment: How hard is it to try that out for yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a boolean type in oracle databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-a-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases)

Comment: @Eomm, not really. That one is oracle specific. I want to know how liquibase handles the fact that oracle doesn't have boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the changelog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

   <changeSet author="arthur" id="42">
      <createTable tableName="bool_test">
        <column name="some_flag" type="boolean"/>
      </createTable>
   </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Run the script

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=bool_test.xml update
```

Show the table definition

```
c:>sqlplus arthur/password

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Tue Dec 20 18:19:21 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'BOOL_TEST') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','BOOL_TEST')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "ARTHUR"."BOOL_TEST"
   (    "SOME_FLAG" NUMBER(1,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't create the constraints then.
Thanks.