# Binary type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, binary

In the SQL Server [`binary type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), is it possible to store something less than one byte?

> binary [ ( n ) ] Fixed-length binary data with a length of n bytes, where n is a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is n bytes.

For example, if I had 8 columns for user preferences, could I store these as 8 separate columns for a combined data size of one byte? Or would this take up 8 bytes. Do any other databases support a `bytes` object that may be less than a byte (or can be packed with other byte/binary columns?)

Comment: Generally speaking the last thing you would worry about is storage. Correctness of your schema should be the first priority. Bit flags are difficult to use in queries and cannot be directly optimized - assuming you need to write tsql queries based on them. Maybe not so important for user preference columns - but you can't predict future needs. And, of course, what happens when the options are changed or expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the SQL Server binary type, is it possible to store something less than one byte?
> For example, if I had 8 columns for user preferences, could I store these as 8 separate columns for a combined data size of one byte?

Yes and yes.

SQL Server will automatically *compact* multiple `bit` columns into a single byte:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of `bit` columns. **If there are 8 or fewer `bit` columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte**. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.
>
> The string values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` can be converted to bit values: `'TRUE'` is converted to `1` and `'FALSE'`is converted to `0`.
>
> Converting to `bit` promotes any nonzero value to `1`.

Personally I advise against using implicit conversion of `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` string values to `bit` column values for reasons I won't go into (and I do lament the lack of a "`bit`-literal" in T-SQL's syntax, though you can always use `1` and `0`).

---

> Do any other databases support a bytes object that may be less than a byte (or can be packed with other byte/binary columns?)

(Note that the SQL *language* does have a built-in nullabe-`boolean` type which is used to represent the intermediate results of expressions such as `EXISTS` and predicates in `WHERE` clauses, but the SQL specification does not require implementations to support `boolean` as a column type - <sub>this is *yet another* reason why the SQL spec authors need a slapping</sub>).

[Oracle, famously, still does not support any `boolean` column types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726758/is-there-any-boolean-type-in-oracle-databases) - which is why you see multi-billion-dollar production databases using `char(1)` to store `'Y'` and `'N'`.

[PostgreSQL supports `boolean` columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-boolean.html), but their documentation does not state if it will compact bitfield columns or not.

[MySQL since version 5.0.3 supports `bit` and `bit(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values). Older versions support `boolean` columns - though it translates the `boolean` keyword into `tinyint(1)`. [MySQL's documentation does not state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html) if it compacts multiple single-bit columns into multiple bytes, however.

Comment: I see, so it's like a `CEILING` function that rounds up to the next byte if its not a round number (multiple of 8), is that correct?

Comment: @david542 -- `which is why you see multi-billion-dollar production databases using char(1)` -- lol, I use `TINYINT(1)` in mysql5.7.

Comment: @David542 Correct, the storage requirement for `n`-many `bit` columns in a table is `ceil( n / 8 )`.