# How do I pass checkbox value as a string instead of boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm using Oracle and I have this in my model

```
public string Completed { get; set; }
```

I guess there's no bool in Oracle. I tried

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.completed)
```

And

```
@Html.CheckBox("Completed")
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a different datatype than string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426145/oracles-lack-of-a-bit-datatype-for-table-columns

Comment: Having a question mark in your property name should throw an error.

Comment: can you give us an example of what checkbox value you're trying to pass? eg. "yes" "no" "maybe so"

Comment: @jPhizzle The question mark is only in the label tag to display. How do I pass a value? I want to pass Y or N instead of true and false. The data type is set as VARCHAR2(1 Byte)

Comment: [Maybe try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730746/getting-checkbox-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue. I have a 1 byte string as data type not a bool

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
<input id="completed" type="checkbox" value="Y" name="completed">
<input type="hidden" value="N" name="completed">
```